# How to investigate webScoket failures on Safari?

Tags: html, websocket

I just started learning WebSockets today. I am using Safari and the following C# as my WebSocket server (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/c_sharp_web_socket_server.aspx).

My client is as simple as the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    try{
    var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8181'); 

    alert(socket.readyState); 
    socket.onopen = function() {
        alert('opened...');
    };
    socket.onclose = function() { 
        alert('closed');

    }; 
    socket.onerror = function(){
        alert('error!'); 
    }; }
    catch(exception){
        alert(exception); 

    }
</script>
```

On  Safari, am getting the message "Closed"  which means the event onclose was raised before the onopen(). I suspecting that the server is closing the connection, any idea? Also, what's the best way to investigate issues like this? any error or reason code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess I figured it out. On Safari you can enable `Developer Tools` and I was getting missing Sec-WebSocket-Origin header so I went ahead and changed the following:

`WebSocket-Origin changed to Sec-WebSocket-Origin`